# How many gpu cores is my program using?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am executing a parallel computation on gpu via thrust. Is there a way to know how many cores I am using? Are all the available cores actually exploited for the computation?

Comment: Most likely all available cores are being used to some degree. The visual profiler can gather statistics to help confirm.

Answer (score 1):

[The visual profile](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-visual-profiler)r will give you a lot of detail about what's going on in your kernel, without the counters that it collects any guesses about occupancy are just that.